# How to remotely access a Mac from my iOS app?

Tags: ios, ipad, mac, network

I'd like to remotely access a Mac mini from my iPad app.   The simplest method appears to be via SSH but I've read this requires jailbreaking the iPad and I don't want that.   Is there an 'Apple approved' method to so this?

I don't currently need access via the internet, just via the local network.   Note that some changes will require password authentication; passwords can be encrypted in the iPad app to ensure security isn't compromised over the network.

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: re ssh there are apps in the App store that allow iPads to use ssh to any other thing so it does not require jailbreak. Using ssh into the iPad from somewhere else would require a jailbreak to run the sshd daemon

Comment: Hi Rob.   I'd like to configure Mac mini settings and accounts from the iPad so the iPad user can influence the configuration e.g. create a sharing account that points at directories of a user account; the user account being chosen by the iPad user.

Comment: Hi Mark.   I'd like to do this from my app rather than an app store app.   Okay, jailbreak only required Mac to iPad not iPad to Mac.   I'd read iOS SSH commands aren't available.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you're an application developer since you said "my iPad app".

SSH works over standard TCP, it does not require jailbreaking, so you could use that (Here's a library to use SSH with: https://github.com/Lejdborg/NMSSH). You'll just need to enable SSH (Remote Login) in the Sharing settings of the OS X computer. I'm not aware of any other non-proprietary services you can use that is built into a Mac to execute commands on it remotely. You could alternatively run your own service running on the Mac to remotely control it.

If all you need is file access, you can use AFP (Apple File Protocol) or SMB (Server Message Block) through File Sharing in Sharing settings in OS X. Or SFTP through Remote Login. You can find example client implementations of those online.

Comment: Thanks 1lann! So if I submitted an app to the app store using NMSSH, Apple would allow it? It might be easier to create my own service; I'd like to change (only a few) Mac settings; having said that SSH is secure and creating a reliable encryption method would be significant effort, so probably best to use NMSSH.